# Fixed Side Panel with Inline Divs

Tags: html, scroll, css

I am trying to figure out how to create the following layout in html.

[image]

I want to have a fixed width panel that is always visible on the left.  Then another panel to the right which contains a variable number of divs.  The panel on the right should fit to the remaining screen size and if there are two many divs inside it show a scroll bar.

If someone could let me know how to do this that would be awesome.  Everything I have tried so far has not worked for some reason or another.

Thanks,
Nathan

My current code:
JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/

The problem here is that when the screen gets small enough a second scrollbar appears on the body so to see the right edge of the last div in the comparison panel I have to scroll over on both scroll bars.

```
.audit_log {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.event_panel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
}

.comparison_panel {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.event_details {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 200px;
}

<body>
<div class="audit_log">
    <div class="event_panel">
    </div>
    <div class="comparison_panel">
        <div class="event_details">
            <p>I Am Details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event_details">
            <p>I Am Details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event_details">
            <p>I Am Details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event_details">
            <p>I Am Details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event_details">
            <p>I Am Details</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is an example of the problem, notice the two scroll bars.

[image]

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle for your existing code

Comment: Added link to js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code this is jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/7jeoaLkv/ ..is this what you are looking for ?

```
<div class="child_fixed">fixed one</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>


 .child_fixed {
     position:fixed;
     height:200px;
     background-color:yellow;
 }
 .parent {
     position:relative;
     left:65px;
     white-space:nowrap;
     max-width:200px;
     overflow:scroll;
 }
 .parent > div {
     display:inline-block;
     height:200px;
     white-space:normal;
     width:80px;
     background:red;
 }
```

Comment: If you make the page smaller you will notice that a second scroll bar appears. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: oh ..so you dont want second scroll bar for height to occur ?

Comment: Height is fine, but there are two horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: Hey @Nath5 do you think this new fiddle is close  ?http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/7jeoaLkv/1/

Comment: Close but the divs in parent need to have a min-width, if you add that and then shrink the window width you will see the second scroll bar.

Comment: im not sure ..but is this near ? http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/7jeoaLkv/9/ @Nath5

Comment: Problem with that is that .bigClass width set to 30% if you set it to something like 70% and then shrink the window you are back to the same problem.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: hi @Nath5 can you try this and let me know what is missing http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/7jeoaLkv/38/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62014/discussion-between-rahul-sambari-and-nath5).

Comment: one thing is that scroll is not working and its getting aligned responsively to the down ..but is the rest of features working as you required?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the outer wrapper is too small. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/91/

```
.parent{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:scroll;
  width:100%;
}
.parent > div{
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:normal;
  width:80px;
  background:red;
}
```

basically have the parent of the scrolling elements be 100% of its parent so the other scrollbar doesn't show up.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the problem with your example, and mine above.  Thanks for the help any ideas?  You can see there is a second scroll bar that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Your example doesn't have the fixed width panel to the left.  If you add that in you will see the problem.